# Parallel fetches capture the component state leading to race condition

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, closures, race-condition

## Description

### What I Need

I want to trigger several fetch-based Promises **in parallel**. Whenever each of these promises resolves, the value should be processed and appended to component state (`items`). In other words, I want the `items` state to be updated with each promise resolution, rather then one time when all promises resolve.

### Issue

The issue is that if I let each promise have a `.then()` handler that processes own resolved value, then `items` state is being captured in each closure. This leads to first handler calling `setState` with `[...items, firstResultItem]`, second -- with `[...items, secondResultItem]` and so on. Each closure is not seeing the changes made to `items` state from the other handler. This race condition results in latest-fetch-wins kind of situation, which is undesireable.

The issue is solved easily if I have a single promise handler applied to `Promise.all(...)`, but this goes against the desired component behavior.

### Thoughts

I was thinking about using `useRef` together with `useState` or find a way to leverage `useEffect`, but I think this is a typical problem that must already have an idiomatic solution.

## Code

- For simplicity, the fetches are faked with `imitateFetch(promiseResolutionValue, delayInMs)`.
- `items` has a default state of a single item; all the new items produced from `imitateFetch` should be **appended** to current state of `items`.
- See **[Executable example on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/parallel-fetches-capture-the-component-state-leading-to-race-condition-u6xgvo?file=/src/App.tsx)**

```
import { useRef, useState } from "react";

export interface Item {
  id: string;
  text: string;
}

export function App() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState<Item[]>([
    { id: new Date().toISOString(), text: new Date().toLocaleTimeString() },
  ]);

  const naiveUpdateItemListWith = (newItemTexts: string[]) => {
    const newItems = newItemTexts.map(newItemText => {
      const item: Item = {
        id: new Date().toISOString(),
        text: newItemText,
      };
      return item;
    });
    setItems([...items, ...newItems]);
  };

  const handleTriggerFetch = () => {
    //   Buggy variant.
    const one = imitateFetch('one', 1000).then(text => naiveUpdateItemListWith([text]));
    const two = imitateFetch('two', 1500).then(text => naiveUpdateItemListWith([text]));
    const three = imitateFetch('three', 2000).then(text => naiveUpdateItemListWith([text]));
    Promise.all([one, two, three]);

    //   These works, but the update happens once, when ALL promises resolve.
    // const one = imitateFetch('one', 1000);
    // const two = imitateFetch('two', 1500);
    // const three = imitateFetch('three', 2000);
    // Promise.all([one, two, three]).then(texts => naiveUpdateItemListWith(texts));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {items.map(item => <div key={item.id}>[{item.id}] -- {item.text}</div>)}

      <button onClick={handleTriggerFetch}>
        Imitate parallel fetches
      </button>
    </div>
  );
} 

function imitateFetch<T>(valueToResolve: T, ms = 1000): Promise<T> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(valueToResolve);
    }, ms);
  });
}
```

Comment: have you tried async await?

Comment: Async/await has nothing to do with the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I misunderstand your question, the solution is actually simple. You can pass an updater function to your `setItems` function, which takes the previous state as an argument, and returns the new state. The updater function [takes the pending state and calculates the next state from it](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useState#updating-state-based-on-the-previous-state), so it would eliminate race conditions.

```js
setItems((i: Item[]) => [...i, ...newItems]);
```

Comment: Lovely! I don't know how I forgot about this state hook details. Definitely read about it. Thank you, Eduardo!